# Debian 6 - Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 - Samba server with 32GB swap - how should i reuse it?

Tags: linux, debian, memory, samba, swap

today i have the mission to tuning a Debian samba file server, previously i never ever touched it.

RAM = 16GB
SWAP = 32GB

first of i ran a parted -l and a free -h and i saw one 3TB hdd:

```
/dev/sda 3TB
/dev/sda1 1MB bios_grub
/dev/sda2 2968GB ext3 / (/opt/share is the samba directory)
/dev/sda3 32GB swap
```

imho a 32GB swap partition is a total madness, so my question is: how can i reuse it? should i reduce it to 4 GB? and what can i do with the remaining 28GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar to [How big should the swap partition be?](https://serverfault.com/questions/19007/how-big-should-the-swap-partition-be?rq=1)
with the twist of how using it.

Assuming that you really want to repartition /dev/sda to create another partition just to increment the usable space of 0.95% of the total you can the new partition as mountpoint for a directory that uses space. You can for example use that to store the logs.

If you can take down the machine and reconfigure it you can easily put on the 24gb partion all the OS, than mount the sda2 partion to /opt/share. So in case something goes wrong with OS upgrade you have a partition that holds just the data. That will help you to recover without too much hassle.